# Box create new folder returns error 400

Tags: php, box-api

I am using box api v2.0 to create new folder over box for logged in user. I get error 400. Given Below is my code please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
public function create_folder($name, $parent_id) 
{
     $url = $this->build_url("/folders");
     $id = json_encode(array('id' => $parent_id));
     $params = array('name' => $name, 'parent' => $id, 'id' => $parent_id);        
     return json_decode($this->post($url, $params), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a 'Bad Request' error. I think this is because the POST body of your request is incorrectly structured.  To fix it, the `$parent_id` must be assigned to an `id` property of a `parent` object.

You want to be sending this JSON POST body:

```
{
   "name":"<$name>", 
   "parent":{
     "id": "<$parent_id>"
   }
}
```

Comment: I did the mentioned modifications. Following code was added by me still I am getting error 400:                                     $params = array('name' => $name, 'parent' => $id);                        it specifies parameters are missing

Comment: Can you capture the HTTP traffic that's being produced by your request? It seems like there might be a formatting issue, but it's hard to tell without seeing what's going across the wire.

Comment: I captured HTTP traffic on api file execution using Wireshark and I save that entire file. If you want to view it I can mail you.